# How to copy from a program that does not let me to copy and give me a QRT file?

Tags: file, text, copy, clipboard

There is a program in my computer that does not let me copy text from it, and when I copy a sentence or text it gives me a QRT extension file.

**Is there a way to copy that text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me to tell you a little about QRT

> QRT files are Uncommon Files primarily associated with QRT Ray Tracing Graphic. *[Solvusoft](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-qrt/)*

There are some good programs to open the **.qrt** files, bellow is some link to that programs download page:

[filext](http://filext.com/file-extension/QRT)

[solvusoft](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-qrt/)

[file.org](http://file.org/extension/qrt)

and if you are going to edit and view text of a QRT file I suggest you to open the QRT file by one of the programs (first download one of the programs to view QRT file) and then take a picture from that QRT file by ***print screen*** key on keyboard. and then convert that image to text by one of the [OCR](http://finereader.abbyy.com/about_ocr/whatis_ocr/) programs. 
If you have image of your QRT file just upload it here to have convert it to text:
[onlineocr](http://www.onlineocr.net/)